# Test FFI functions in Rust

Tags: rust, ffi

I have a lib in Rust that exposes some FFI functions and I would like to know how to call these functions in a console app and if there is a way to test them via the Linux terminal?

PS: I know the lib is working because I can make the call in C#.

lib implementation:

```
const CUR_VERSION: &str = "0.1";

#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn get_version() -> *const c_char {
    let c_string = CString::new(CUR_VERSION).expect("CString::new failed");
    c_string.into_raw()
}
```

In the console application I tried this without success:

```
extern crate core;
use std::ffi::c_char;

#[cfg_attr(unix, link(name = "my_dll.so", kind = "dylib"))]
extern "C" {
    fn get_version() -> *const c_char;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("Result: {:?}", get_version());
    }
}
```

Error Code

[image]

Comment: "without success" → what went wrong? Did it fail to compile? With what error? Did it compile but fail to run? With what error? Did it compile and run but fail to give the expected result? What did you expect and what happened instead?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't send the error.
error: linking failed with `cc`: exit status: 1
I already provided the full path too, but I get the same error.

Comment: Please post the full output in the question.

Comment: I put the image of the error in the question because it was too big.

Comment: Did you put the file in the search path? Also, it needs to be named `libmy_dll.so`, and you need to drop the `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix in the code.

Comment: It's complaining that my_dll.so doesn't exist.  Is it there?

Comment: I removed the lib and .so and it worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `name` passed to `link` is not the file name, it's the library name. On Linux, file names are made from library names by adding a `.so` extension and a `lib` prefix. So a library `foo` will have a file name `libfoo.so`.